# Configure Rundeck to use an external DB

Tags: rundeck

I'm configuring `Rundeck` to run using an external Oracle DB.
I set rundeck-config.properties

```
#loglevel.default is the default log level for jobs: ERROR,WARN,INFO,VERBOSE,DEBUG
loglevel.default=INFO
rdeck.base=${rdeck.base}

#rss.enabled if set to true enables RSS feeds that are public (non-authenticated)
rss.enabled=false
grails.serverURL=http://${server.hostname}:${server.http.port}${server.web.context}
dataSource.dbCreate = update
#dataSource.url = jdbc:h2:file:${server.datastore.path};MVCC=true
dataSource.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@//10.237.154.215:1521/Q12353AP10
dataSource.driverClassName = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
dataSource.username = userrundeck5
dataSource.password = Rundeck_0001
#dataSource.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
dataSource.dialect = com.rundeck.hibernate.RundeckOracleDialect
hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true

# Pre Auth mode settings
rundeck.security.authorization.preauthenticated.enabled=false
rundeck.security.authorization.preauthenticated.attributeName=REMOTE_USER_GROUPS
rundeck.security.authorization.preauthenticated.delimiter=,
# Header from which to obtain user name
rundeck.security.authorization.preauthenticated.userNameHeader=X-Forwarded-Uuid
# Header from which to obtain list of roles
rundeck.security.authorization.preauthenticated.userRolesHeader=X-Forwarded-Roles
# Redirect to upstream logout url
rundeck.security.authorization.preauthenticated.redirectLogout=false
rundeck.security.authorization.preauthenticated.redirectUrl=/oauth2/sign_in
```

During the start I see:

```
    2018-06-14 18:00:29.682:INFO:/rundeck:main: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2018-06-14 18:00:39,914 [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table "auth_token" add constraint FK_aiqc20kpjasth5bxogsragoif foreign key (user_id) references "rduser"
2018-06-14 18:00:39,914 [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - ORA-02275: such a referential constraint already exists in the table

2018-06-14 18:00:39,917 [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table "log_file_storage_request" add constraint FK_trqsa9so0qcv6okcd6fan88yf foreign key (execution_id) references "execution"
2018-06-14 18:00:39,917 [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - ORA-02275: such a referential constraint already exists in the table
```

How can I fix?

Thanks in advance,
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

I solved using the guide at the following page : http://support.rundeck.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2447898-oracle-script-